# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance com.test.User#5

Tags: jpa, sql-delete, entitymanager, illegalargumentexception

I have a java EE project using JPA (transaction-type="JTA"), hibernate as provider. I write my beans to handle the CRUD things. The program running in JBOSS 7 AS.

I have an EntityManagerDAO :

```
@Stateful
public class EntityManagerDao implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dtdJpa")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Object updateObject(Object object) {
        object = entityManager.merge(object);
        return object;
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void createObject(Object object) {
        entityManager.persist(object);
    }

    public void refresh(Object object) {
        entityManager.refresh(object);
    }

    public <T> T find(Class<T> clazz, Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void deleteObject(Object object) {
        entityManager.remove(object);
    }
}
```

but when I invoke `deleteObject`, this exception comes out.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance com.test.User#5

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

[`EntityManager#remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) works only on entities which are managed in the current transaction/context. In your case, you're retrieving the entity in an earlier transaction, storing it in the HTTP session and then attempting to remove it in a different transaction/context. This just won't work.

You need to check if the entity is managed by [`EntityManager#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) and if not, then make it managed it [`EntityManager#merge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29).

Basically, the `delete()` method of your business service class should look like this:

```
em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
```

Comment: @BalusC In em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
, if em(contains(entity) is false then are you removing entityToBeRemoved = em.merge(entity) , entityToBeRemoved? Are you removing what returns from em.merge(entity) ?

Comment: Because according to the answer in the question I mentioned you need:    a = em.merge(a); // merge and assign a to the attached entity 
    em.remove(a); // remove the attached entity

Comment: @BalusC In using em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity)); are there any dangers related. Because I was getting this error and I changed to your solution and it works. But the Java experts on my team are not so sure.

Comment: @BalusC Will `em.remove(em.getReference(...))` also work?

Comment: @BalusC man.. you are a genius. I had the same issue. but I moved my 
 transaction to service layer and fixed my problem. Actually my case was a bit different, from the UI I was getting just the ID of the user, so In my service I was making 2 calls to the DB. One to check if the user exists and the second to delete. Since Transaction was at the DAO layer as you said it was a separate transaction. So i moved it to Service layer and it worked.. thanks again for the clear explanation.

Comment: I think this answer can be improved if the phrase entityManager.close is also mentioned here :D

Comment: In case this burns anyone else, it's important to remove() the object that was merged. I'm green with Hibernate, so I mistakenly thought the merge mutated the object and then you suddenly had a managed object. This apparently is not so.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I got the same error, when I tried to delete an object 
using,

```
session.delete(obj)
```

without creating any transaction before that.

And the problem is solved by creating the transaction first(session.beginTransaction() and then deleting the object.

I hope my answer will help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes its simply because you are missing the @Transaction annotation for add, remove, update operations.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The detached entity should be re-attached. As @BalusC mentioned, using `EntityManager.merge()` should be used to attach the detached entity. `EntityManager.merge()` generates SQL Query which fetches the current state of the entity, on which `EntityManager.remove()` has to be performed. But in my case it didn't worked. 
Try `EntityManager.remove(EntityManager.find(Class<T>,arg))` instead. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if I query an object from the DB then closed the entity manager then do a DB delete, the problem happens. Or if I copy that loaded object to another instance then do a delete, this problem also happens.
In my opinion there are 2 things to keep note:

- The object must be in the same session that was created by the Entity Manager
- And the object mustn't be transferred to another object while the Entity Manager's session is still opened.

Cheers